# How to assemble file from byte[] via HTTP request method C#

Tags: c#, arrays, file, http-post

I want to send file as byte[] to another PC via HTTP POST method. What is the most efficient way to assemble the file from byte[] on the other side? I am using `File.ReadAllBytes` method to get byte[] from file.

Comment: Maybe File.WriteAllBytes?

Comment: I tried File.WriteAllBytes locally but I don't know if it is going to work on other PC

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tcp the network protocol will make sure that your stream is coming in the right order and without dropped parts. Therefore, the simplest readstream will be the most efficient. If you want to use parallel routes and play with the datagrams.
If the file is large you will have to transmit and receive it in chunks. But the IP streams can hide that from you.

For example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. I used this method to call api method and send file as byte[]. I tried sending whole byte[] but api method wasn't able to recive it.

```
private static async void SendFiles(string path)
        {    
            var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
            var length = bytes.Length;

            foreach (var b in bytes)
            {
                length--;
                string sendFilesUrl = $"http://api/communication/sendF/{b}/{length}";

                StringContent queryString = new StringContent(bytes.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");          

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(sendFilesUrl, queryString);

                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }
```

My api method is

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("sendF/{b}/{length}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage SendF([FromUri]byte[] b, [FromUri]int length)
        {
            if(length != 0)
            {
                bytes.AddRange(b);                
            }
            else
            {
                File.WriteAllBytes(@"G:\test\test.exe", bytes.ToArray<byte>());
            }

            return CreateResponse(client);
        }
```

This code works for me but it takes very long to pass all bytes if the file is large. Currently I'm searching for more efficient way of sending bytes. One solution that came to my mind is to send byte[] in chunks